# Redshift performance boost for star schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-redshift

We have one fact table and 3 dimension.

1. Dim is Process where is process number, status either open or close, PK and several other columns
2. Dim is Brand with several brands ,PK etc.
3. Dim is Supplier with lot of suppliers,PK etc.
4. Fack table with FK's to the dimension and measure like best BID , quantity

Let's suppose I want query
a) for specific supplier
b) for specific brand
c) all open processes for a specific brand
d) all closed processes for a specific supplier.
e) gor specific process

In the fact there could a one process for always 1 brand but with more than 1
supplier.

In Oracle I would create bitmap Index for supplier , brand, process status and process. So I can query faster all thouse scenarios.

What would be the best way to do it in Redshift? How to restric the big fact table best way? The queried columns are in fimension so there will be always full scan of the fact table? Should I place for example the status of the process as attribute in fact table to scan just a half table if there 50:50 open vs closed processes etc?

I am pretty sure the dimension will have distribution style ALL cause there are not so big amd to avoid broadcasting but what else if sometimes just one predicate will be used in the Where Clause sometimes more than 1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rule for Amazon Redshift is:

- The column typically used in a `WHERE` should be the `SORTKEY`
- The column typically used in a `JOIN` should be in the `DISTKEY`

When Redshift stores data on disk, each 1MB block has a 'zone map' that identifies the maximum and minimum value for the column (it's a columnar database, so columns are stored separately). This means Redshift can 'skip over' disk blocks that don't contain a relevant value. This is where the SORTKEY provides the most benefit.

See also: [Choose the best sort key - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html)

Comment: Yes I read a lot of this distkey,sortkey etc. So in my case I should use gor all my dimensions the Where clause fields as sortkeys then for my fact table there are multiple FK's related to my dimension and that is the issue. I have several Where clause scenarios so I can not sort for all of them. Diskey should be also just one column in a fact, should be the one which give the most result from one of the dimension.e.g. if process dimension gives the most rows in join then this the FK in fact table should be my distkey?

Comment: It's worth understanding what they actually do, and then you can make your best judgement. The DISTKEY divides the data amongst nodes in the cluster. If two tables are JOINed, then it is best that they both use the same DISTKEY since the same data for each key will be stored on the same node. When the tables are JOINed, having the same distribution will minimise the amount of data that needs to be sent between the nodes. These days Redshift can set these parameters [automatically](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Creating_tables.html) so you could just set it to `AUTO`.